# Remove brackets around text and add colon at the end

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a long string, and would like to replace occurrences of this kind:

```
'eggs (spam): tomatoes'
```

with ones of this kind:

```
'eggs : spam tomatoes'
```

That is to say, if there is a pattern of the kind 'left bracket, text, right bracket, double-colon, space', then I would like it to be replaced with 'double-colon, space, text'.

I have tried writing the following:

```
import re
re.sub('\(.+\): ', '', 'eggs (spam): tomatoes')
```

but (unsurprisingly) it removes the bracketed text completely, and I don't know how to retain the text which was previously bracketed in the 'replace' part of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with capturing groups:

```
re.sub(r"\(([^()]*)\)(:)", r"\2 \1", 'eggs (spam): tomatoes')
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ASCWQ5/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `(` Start of capturing group one

  - `[^()]*` Match any thing between
- `)` End of capturing group one
- `\)` Match closing parenthesis
- `(:)` Capture a colon (CG #2)

Replacement string `"\2 \1"` means replacement should follow second capturing group data then a space then first capturing group data.

Comment: I just tried running it and got this output `'eggs $2 $1 tomatoes'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub('\((.*?)\): ', r':\1 ', 'eggs (spam): tomatoes')`

**Demo:**

```
import re
print(re.sub('\((.*?)\): ', r':\1 ', 'eggs (spam): tomatoes'))
```

**Output:**

```
eggs :spam tomatoes
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are selecting from the opening parenthesis until the closing parenthesis including the colon and replacing that with an empty string. That is why it removes the bracketed text completely.

You might use 2 capturing groups and replace with group 2 group 1:

[`\((.+?)\)(:)`](https://regex101.com/r/ulAE1W/2/)

- `\(` Match literally
- `(.+?)` Capture in group 1 `\\1` any character one or more times non greedy
- `\)` Match literally
- `(:)` Capture a colon in group 2 `\\2`

For example:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"\((.+?)\)(:)", "\\2 \\1", 'eggs (spam): tomatoes'))
```

That will give you:

```
eggs : spam tomatoes
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UVWV55315)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> re.sub('\((.*)\): ', ': \\1 ', 'eggs (spam): tomatoes')
eggs : spam tomatoes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` and `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = 'eggs (spam): tomatoes'
new_s = re.sub('\(\w+\):', '{}', s).format(*[f': {i}' for i in re.findall('\((.*?)\)', s)])
```

Output:

```
'eggs : spam tomatoes'
```